# Processing of a collection of files (images) and plotting a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm working on my project. So far, I've been doing some stuff about initial images processing. Like I've got 500 images, where were taken with a fixed camera. But some of them were total dark or too bright. I'm supposed to delete them to get valuable images, and then I could do some further research.

In order to achieve it,  I should get the average of intensity (R+G+B/3) of that whole 500 images. And then plot a histogram. It means I must have the average of intensity for each picture, and plot it as a histogram. Probably, I am supposed to use for loop to analyze that 500 images.

So far, this is my code.

```
img = cv2.imread('IMAG0001.JPG')
avg_color_per_row = numpy.average(img, axis=0)
avg_color = numpy.average(avg_color_per_row, axis=0)
print sum(avg_color)/3
```

Probably, it is the average of intensity for only one image, but if I wanted to analyze the total 500 images in a folder and plot it as a histogram, how am I supposed to do?

Comment: Have you at least tried to research about how to list files in a directory?

Comment: "Probably, I am supposed to use for loop" - that is a good idea. You should learn how to use for loops (and other kinds of loops) in Python, for example [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop). Once that's done, learn how to plot a histogram with [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/hist.html), for example.

Comment: 500 is not a ton, is not even big amount of data in 2018. Just loop over that

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it. I should get familiar with for loops and other kinds of loops in Python as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path.

500 images is not a big amount of files. So the first thing to implement in this code would be a for loop to go through all the 500 images, read them, take the information you want and store it. Look for the `os` library, where you can loop over the image files (that are in a specified directory), then you use `matplotlib`to plot the histogram outside the for loop using a numpy array that contains all the avg_color data you collected over the loop. A draft of the solution would be something like this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

results = [] 
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith('.JPG')]: # to loop over all images you have on the directory
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        avg_color_per_row = numpy.average(img, axis=0)
        avg_color = numpy.average(avg_color_per_row, axis=0)
        results.append(avg_color)
np_results = np.array(results) # to make results a numpy array
plt.hist(np_results)
plt.show() # to show the histogram
```

I hope that helps you to get the solution you want!

Comment: I will try it. Thank you so much for your help. In term of os.walk(), I just put the file names in a directory, like where did I store the 500 images?

Comment: Put the images in the same directory as the script you are going to execute, or in a subdirectory of this, and you should be good to go

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thank you so much.  You are my lord:)....   By the way, Could you tell me a bit what does the " f for f" represent in the for loop?  And Do you have some useful books or e-books that you highly recommend to let me get familiar with the images processing in Python?

Comment: I’m glad it worked! Don’t forget to vote up and mark this as an accepted answer to help others that have the same issue as you to identify the good solution.

Comment: Oh, by the way. I've got the histogram of what I expect. The x-coordinate means the intensity of the images, which is from 0 to 180. But, I'm not sure what does the y-axis mean in the histogram, the range of it is also between 0 to 180.

Comment: About the f for f part: everything inside that [] is called a list comprehension. It looks a little bit complicated, but in a closer look you will see that it just filters the original file names list, leaving just the ones that end with “.JPG”. I added that to make sure you are just processing the images, and if another file type gets there for mistake it will not be processed (and maybe cause an error)

Comment: About the image processing references: I actually don’t have one for you. I’ve never done image processing. The stuff we did here is basic and intermediate python stuff. I would recommend you to take some online courses on python and get active on stackoverflow. That’s where I learned a lot

Comment: About the histogram: the y-axis is the number of occurrences of each os those values. Remember, histograms shows a distribution of the values you plot

Comment: My lord, I finally got that. Thank you so much. I may take some online courses at coursera.....The friends of mine just told me there were plenty of courses that I could choose. Anyway, really appreciate your help with patience.